# What standard are these backslash escape sequences using?

Tags: python, escaping, text-processing

I'm doing some text processing on [Websters Unabridged Dictionary](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/673) and have come across some escape sequences that don't conform to any standard (i.e., they are not HTML, CSS, Unicode, etc escape sequences) that I know of.

Some sample text:

```
<h1>Galore</h1>
<Xpage=610>

<hw>Ga*lore"</hw> <tt>(?)</tt>, <tt>n. & a.</tt> <ety>[Scot. <ets>gelore</ets>, <ets>gilore</ets>, <ets>galore</ets>, fr. <ets>Gael</ets>. <ets>gu le\'95r</ets>, enough; <ets>gu-</ets> to, also an adverbial prefix + <ets>le\'95r</ets>, <ets>le\'95ir</ets>, enough; or fr. Ir. <ets>goleor</ets>, the same word.]</ety> <def>Plenty; abundance; in abundance.</def>
```

They are all of the form `\'xy` where `x`, `y` are any digit in `[0-9]` or letter in `[a-f]`. Clearly, they agree in form with [RTF escape sequences](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch04.html). However, the characters they are supposed to represent are nowhere near correct.

For the ones that appear in the data I want I have figured out that:

```
{
   "\'80": "Ç",
   "\'81": "ü",
   "\'82": "é",
   "\'83": "â",
   "\'84": "ä",
   "\'85": "à",
   "\'86": "å",
   "\'87": "ç",
   "\'88": "ê",
   "\'89": "ë",
   "\'90": "É",
   "\'91": "æ",
   "\'92": "Æ",
   "\'93": "ô",
   "\'94": "ö",
   "\'95": "ò",
   "\'96": "û",
   "\'97": "ù"
}
```

At first I thought that maybe it was a simple wrap-around error (each hexvalue `xy` is off by the same amount), but this is not true by looking at `ç` and `ö` and comparing their offset to the correct values or by noting that if `Ç` is `\'80`, then `ü` should be `\'b5`.

For completeness, all the values I found with the regex `r"\\\'[\d\w]{2,2}"` (74 in total) are:

```
\'3c
\'3e
\'80
\'81
\'82
\'83
\'84
\'85
\'86
\'87
\'88
\'89
\'8a
\'8b
\'8c
\'8d
\'90
\'91
\'92
\'93
\'94
\'95
\'96
\'97
\'9a
\'9c
\'a0
\'a1
\'a2
\'a3
\'a4
\'a6
\'a7
\'ab
\'ac
\'b5
\'b6
\'b7
\'b8
\'bd
\'be
\'bf
\'c3
\'c5
\'c6
\'c7
\'c8
\'c9
\'cb
\'cc
\'ce
\'cf
\'d0
\'d1
\'d2
\'d3
\'d4
\'d6
\'dc
\'dd
\'de
\'df
\'dh
\'eb
\'ed
\'ee
\'ef
\'f0
\'f4
\'f5
\'f6
\'f7
\'f8
\'fb
```

Can anyone tell me what standard these escape sequences are obeying? A link to a table or a library that will convert them into Unicode would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

Further processing revealed that:

```
{
   "\'d1": "Œ",
   "\'d2": "œ",
   "\'ee": "ã"
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that while characters in `\'80 - \'a5` conform to the [IBM codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), whoever made the document had decided to use a custom mapping for characters not in the original encoding, alas.

Comment: It may be unique to this file format, not a standard.

Comment: @MrLister Indeed that seems to be it, at least for the correspondences that I had figured out. Unfortunately, it appears that whoever made the document decided to overcome the lack of e.g. `ã` by choosing `\'ee`, which means it no longer conforms to any IBM codepage as far as I can tell (the ones with `ã` all have `\'c6` instead)... But this does mean I can automatically decode for the range `\'80 - \'a5`, which will help. I will update the question. Feel free to provide this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: But you already said so in the edit to the question, and I can't think of anything to add. Now I've done some searching, and there are variants to codepage 437 that contain more accented letters, such as [850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), [858](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_858), [865](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_865) and so on,but none that have Œ, œ and ã in those positions. If someone stumbles upon one that fits, they can post an answer.